# A set for which it is hard to determine whether or not it is countable.

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

I got thinking recently, while trying to come up with a problem, that I did not know of any sets which were reasonable to define but for which it was very difficult to determine whether or not they were countable or uncountable.

When one first learns these concepts, it can be difficult, but with some experience, a mathematician can look at most sets which he or she meets in day-to-day and say almost immediately 'countable' or 'uncountable'.

> What examples of sets are there for
>   which determining whether or not they
>   are countable is a difficult problem?

I won't define 'difficult' too rigorously but ideally I'm looking for something which any grad student *can* think about but which most would still be thinking about after 10 minutes.

Comment: Strong measure zero set...  
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48453/a-set-that-can-be-covered-by-arbitrarily-small-intervals  


Comment: Are you only interested in sets that are obviously infinite?  If not, I guess you can give definitions that define sets that are either empty or very large.

Comment: Maybe you should change it to "sets for which it is hard to guess their cardinality"? Then there's room for other nice questions like the cardinality of the set of all continuous real valued functions (this example is not difficult, though, but maybe there are others in this vain)

Answer (score 22):

A [standard problem of this type](http://books.google.com/books?id=ElSi5V5uS2MC&lpg=PA60&ots=_n8S5U40Mz&dq=figure%2520eights%2520in%2520the%2520plane%2520countable&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q=figure%2520eights%2520in%2520the%2520plane%2520countable&f=false) is, can one draw uncountably many non-intersecting, non-degenerate figure-eights in the plane?  The problem is trivially "yes" for circles, rather than figure-eights, so I found this problem surprising when I first saw it.

Comment: This does not quite meet answer the original question, but indeed leads to an interesting class of puzzles.  Perhaps it would deserve its own threads.  

A related question is how many thumbtacks you can place in the 3-space so that no two intersect.  A thumbtack is a union of a disk and a segment one of whose endpoints is an interior point of the disk but the other endpoint is not in the plane of the disk.  (The answer is countably many.)

Comment: The thumbtack question can be also done in the plane: how many nonintersecting figure-Ts can one draw in the plane?

Answer (score 20):

If it is just to puzzle the graduate students for 10+ minutes, consider the set of reals $a>1$ such that for some $K>0$ the distance from $Ka^n$ to the nearest integer tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. The answer is, indeed, next to obvious but I've seen quite a few graduate students that weren't able to do it off hand. Now take a stopwatch and see how soon you'll solve this one yourself :).

Comment: Obvious subset? It is not even known whether it is a subset of algebraic numbers! :)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my "solution" relied on the fact that the quotient of two integers is an integer.

Comment: I thought I solved this until I've seen fedja's comment. The subset in question is not very exotic, its just described in an obscure way (like writing "the set of all non trivial solutions for x^3+y^3=z^3" for the empty set)...

Comment: @fedja: I must be right there with those poor grad students. Can you maybe give a hint?

Comment: @Laurent: Well, they are all computable numbers. Also someone asked about this on math.stackexchange. I'm not sure whether it is the same as Fedja's "next to obvious" answer, but I posted mine as an answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28543/sequence-that-approaches-integers/28587#28587

Comment: @George. Yes, this is the quickest way to see it. 
@mathahada The set is actually pretty exotic even if it is what most people believe it is. If you don't believe me, just try to answer the question whether it is closed.

Answer (score 18):

How about the set of $d$-dimensional manifolds, up to homeomorphism?

I believe it is known for *compact* manifolds that this is a countable set (reference?), but I think this is not obvious.  If we include non-compact manifolds I don't know the answer.

Comment: Surely there are uncountably many.  Just remove countably many tame knots from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, there are uncountably many ways to do this.

Comment: Work of Kerekjarto and Richards implies there are at least as many non-compact separable surfaces as there are triples $(X,Y,Z)$ with $Z\subseteq Y\subseteq X$ a chain of of compact, separable, totally disconnected spaces. There are too many of these for surfaces to be countable, no?

Comment: A quick google search yields deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/2027.42/32762/1/0000133.pdf , but I don't know what the "canonical" reference is.

Comment: A variant for $d=2$: the number of discrete subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb R)$ up to conjugacy.

Comment: @Kimball : That's uncountable.  It's even uncountable if you look at cyclic subgroups up to conjugacy, which are classified by the absolute value of the trace of a generator.

Comment: @Tim: ah yes, I suppose it was easier than I was thinking.  Is it less clear if you ask about the number of subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: By the way, unlike exotic R^4's, there are at most countably many distinct exotic 4-spheres, according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example where it is *hard in a proof-theoretic sense* to determine whether a set is countable.

Jan Reimann and Theodore A. Slaman (in the paper [Randomness for continuous measures](http://www.math.psu.edu/reimann/Publications/continuous_randomness_draft.pdf)) study randomness with respect to continuous measures on $2^\mathbb N$.

They show that for every $n$, the set NCR$_n$ of elements of $2^\mathbb N$ that are not $n$-random (Martin-Löf random relative to the $n$th iterate of the halting problem) with respect to any continuous probability measure, is countable. Furthermore, they show that for every $k\in\mathbb N$, there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that the statement

> NCR$_n$ is countable

cannot be proven in the theory

> ZFC$^-$ + "There exists $k$ iterates of the power set of $\mathbb N$",

where ZFC$^-$ denotes Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with choice, minus the power set axiom.

In other words, if you don't want to assume that the sets $\mathbb N$, $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb N))$, ... exist then you cannot prove that *all but countably many real numbers look random w.r.t. some probability distribution*.

Comment: Bjørn, does the Borel rank of the NCR$_n$ change depending on how many iterates of the power set of the natural numbers are assumed?

Comment: So, depending on how many iterates you have, you can go from $\Pi_{1}^{1}\setminus\Delta_{1}^{1}$ to $\Sigma_{2}^{0}$? (Wow!)

Comment: This example is missing the condition in the statement of the problem that any graduate student *can* think about it, although I'll grant you that they'd still not have an answer after 10 minutes.

Comment: @Tanmay: apparently they show NCR$_n$ is properly $\mathbf\Pi^1_1$ as soon as there are not enough power sets (and countable hence $\mathbf\Sigma^0_2$ when there are).

Answer (score 14):

Does there exists an uncountable family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the intersection of any two sets is finite?  Somewhat surprisingly the answer is yes.

Comment: Along similar lines, is there an uncountable family of subsets of $\mathbb N$ that is totally ordered by inclusion?  This can cause quite a bit of head-scratching until you realize that there's a two-word solution.

Comment: @Tony: Please give me a hint where I can learn more about this!

Comment: Tim, I realize one of "there is" or "there isn't" is a two-word solution. 

Comment: @Hans: Given an infinite sequence of 1s and 2s, its initial segments are numbers (written in decimal notation, for example), so any such sequence corresponds to an infinite subset of ${\mathbb N}$, and any two of these sets have finite intersection.

Comment: @Hans: Tony's problem appears in Donald Newman's book _A Problem Seminar_ and was also problem B-4 on the 1989 Putnam exam. @KConrad: "there is" or "there isn't" is a two-word _answer_ but there is a two-word phrase that gives a _complete solution_ to the problem I posed.

Comment: Tim: I thought of a solution but perhaps its different from yours because its not a two word phrase. A good way is to enumerate the rationals and for every real number $r$ let $A_r$ be the set of all those $n$ such that $q_n < r$. I thought of two candidate two word phrases: omega-one and "enumerating rationals", but the first doesn't work and the second is very far from a complete solution

Comment: I believe the answer Tim is looking for is "Dedekind cuts".

Comment: Tony's example here appears, interestingly enough, in a book on Banach space theory; in Albiac and Kalton's *Topics in Banach Space Theory*, it appears on page 45 as Lemma 2.5.3. There it is used to show (Theorem 2.5.4) that there is no continuous linear projection of $\ell_\infty$ onto its closed subspace $c_0$.

Comment: @Tim and Philip: Thanks for the references!

Comment: @Philip: In fact, this is but one of a family of results in infinitary combinatorics that one encounters with some frequency in the theory of Banach spaces. Recent years have seen a steep increment in the sophistication of the set theory being directly applied in this area. 

Comment: @Andres: Indeed, as I progressed through my graduate studies I noticed precisely what you claim above. As someone who hopes to make further contributions to Banach space theory, learning more set theory, combinatorics and descriptive set theory is now high on my priority list.

Comment: For me, even more surprising than the existence of such an uncountable family, is the fact that any countable family (of subsets of $\mathbb N$ such that the intersection of any two elements of the family is finite) can still be further extended, i.e. there is another infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ whose intersection with any set from the previous family is still finite.

Comment: @David: I think this is false.  Let the family consist of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, together with $\mathbb{N}$ itself.  One cannot extend this family while maintaining the finite intersection property.  

Comment: @Tony: I believe this discussion is only about infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks, I see what David is trying to say now. For a proof of his claim, let $(X_i)$ be an enumeration of the family. For each $i$ choose $x_i \in X_i$ such that $x_i$ is not in the union of the previous $i−1$ sets. We can then extend the family by adding $X:=(x_i)$ to it.

Comment: @David: Actually it is not very hard to add one more to a countable family, the surprising part is that it carries over to the uncountable case. For example, every countable ordinal can be embedding into the rationals, but $\omega_1$ cannot be embedded into it (even without preserving the order).

Comment: @Hans for any real number $a$ take a sequence of rationals converging to $a$. Of course this is essentially the same construction as Andrés'.

Comment: @Fedor: Just to let you know: I received your comment. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 11):

This is of the "to puzzle graduate students" variety, but I was taken enough with it to write it up in a [short note](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/coveringnumbersv2.pdf):

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, of dimension at least $2$, and consider coverings $\mathcal{C} = (W_i)$ of $V$ by proper subspaces.  Does there exist a countable covering $\mathcal{C}$?  (It depends on $\dim V$ and $\# F$, but perhaps not exactly as you expect!)

Answer (score 11):

I'll be the obnoxious one: The set of subsets $S$ of $\{ x+iy \in \mathbb{C}, \ 1/2 < x < 1 \}$ such that $\zeta(s)$ restricted to $S$ is zero.

Comment: HAH. $\!\!\!\!\!$

Comment: And that's Mornington Crescent!

Answer (score 10):

This example is from the book "A problem Seminar" by D.J. Newman:

Let $F$ be an infinite field and let $f: F \times F \to F$ be a function of two variables such that $f(x_0,y)$ is a polynomial in $y$ for every $x_0 \in F$ and $f(x,y_0)$ is a polynomial in $x$ for every $y_0 \in F$. (Of course, being a polynomial for a function $f: F \to F$ means  there exists
$p(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(x)=p(x)$ for all $x \in F$.) Now, is $f$ itself necessarily a polynomial?

Surprisingly the answer depends on the cardinality of $F$. It is negative when $F$ is countable and positive when $F $ is uncountable. For countable $F$, enumerate the elements as $a_1, a_2, \dots $ and consider
$$ f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots (x-a_i)(y-a_1)\cdots (y-a_i) $$

It is obvious that $f$ satisfies the condition, and not hard to show that it is not a polynomial.

Comment: Very nice. How to prove that $f$ must be a polynomial if $F$ is uncountable?

Comment: Start by noticing that for infinitely (in fact, uncountably) many y, f(x, y) has the same degree. Now go hunt for their coefficients.

Comment: Interesting proof. This reminds me the Hartogs' theorem, which states that if $F(z_1,z_2)$ is analytic (which is next to polynomial) in the complex variables $z_1$ and $z_2$ seperately, then $F(z_1,z_2)$ is analytic jointly in $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Answer (score 8):

An elementary example which any grad can think about. Hope it will require 10 mins for most of them to figure out (or recall) the proof:

The set of discontinuous points of a non-decreasing function.

Or, making it more geometric, (under suitable assumptions) the set of the radius $r$ such that a given Borel measure charges the $r$-sphere.

Or, based on the first result, the set of non-differentiable points of a convex function on the real line.

Comment: and, on the same lines, the set of *strict* local maximum points, for a function of one real variable.  

Answer (score 5):

The collection of all compact subsets of the real line up to homeomorphism

Comment: You might prove this as follows (it is overkill but I like fact (a))
(a) Any countable metrizable compact space is homeomorphic to a subset of the real line (Hint: Baire category thm). The hypothesis "metrizable" is useless as any countable (Hausdorff) compact space is metrizable but it makes things easier.
(b) There are uncountably many countable metrizable compact spaces up to homeomorphism (use e.g Cantor-Bendixson rank).


Comment: Better: every countable metric (not just compact) can be embedded in Q, and every countable compact metric is homeomorphic to a countable ordinal

Answer (score 4):

The set of isomorphism classes of n-dimensional simple Lie algebras over some field.

The set of isomorphism classes of n-dimensional Hopf algebras over some field.

Comment: +1: also you should ask about the set of isomorphism classes of all $n$-dimensional Lie algebras over a field (why not?).

Answer (score 4):

Another puzzle: The set of x such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin(n! \pi x) = 0 $.

Answer (score 2):

Pick some misleadingly specific class of finite CW-complexes (e.g. the spheres) and ask for the cardinality of the set of homotopy classes of continuous maps between them. Whether this is easy or hard depends on whether you're familiar with simplicial approximation...

Answer (score 0):

Maximal set of mutually disjoint $Y$'s in the plane (a $Y$ is the image by a continuous injection of the usual $Y$ made of $3$ segments).

Comment: For the answer to be well defined (unique) the Y has to include the 3 endpoints?

Comment: See this answer (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59115/a-set-for-which-it-is-hard-to-determine-whether-or-not-it-is-countable/59132#59132) and my comment.