# Is there a surjective lattice homomorphism $f: {\cal L}\to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: lattice-theory

Let ${\cal L}$ be defined as in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215582/how-big-is-the-lattice-of-all-functions). Is there a surjective lattice homomorphism $f: {\cal L}\to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all functions, ordered point-wise?

Comment: I think $\mathcal L$ has a cofinal $\omega$-chain and $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ does not. (For the chain in $\mathcal L$, consider the sequence $f_k(n) = n+k$, $k=1, 2, 3, \ldots$.)

Comment: Oh - right -- excellent argument! Can you quickly put this in an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathcal L$ has a cofinal $\omega$-chain and $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ does not.