# Is there an uncountable Borel almost disjoint family?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Here we are considering subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of $2^\omega$, which are in correspondence with families of subsets of $\omega$ (sets of "reals").  Such a family is *Borel* if it is a Borel subset of $2^\omega$ under the usual topology.

Such a family is *almost disjoint* if, for every pair $X\not=Y$ from $\mathcal{F}$, $X\cap Y$ is finite.

*Note:* the question originally only required that the symmetric difference between $X$ and $Y$ be infinite, which is substantially weaker.

Countable almost disjoint families can be constructed fairly trivially.  Uncountable almost disjoint families exist, and are a standard object of study in some branches of set theory.  However, the constructions I've seen do not result in a Borel set.  Can this be done?  Can $\mathcal{F}\subset 2^\omega$ be an uncountable Borel set which is an almost disjoint family?

Comment: If you look at the tree $2^{<\omega}$, the set of branches is almost disjoint.

Comment: Seems relevant: http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/khomskii/papers/Brendle_Khomskii_mad_families_Revised.pdf

Comment: Your definition of "almost disjoint" is much weaker than the usual one, which would be "for every pair $X\neq Y$ from $\mathcal{F}$, $X\cap Y$ is finite".  In any case, Asaf's example satisfies both definitions.

Comment: Note that using your weaker definition of almost disjoint, you could also just take the set of complete theories in your favorite (nontrivial) language.

Comment: I think it's a typo: the proposed "weak" definition of almost disjointness leads to families that are not at all disjoint in any typical sense. For example, $\{(-\infty,x)\cap\mathbb{Q}: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ... then you have to show complete theories are Borel

Comment: @GeraldEdgar That's easy, though. Being a complete theory (coded appropriately as a subset of $\omega$) is a $\Pi^0_1$ property - in fact, the set of codes for complete theories is closed!

Comment: Asaf's example is Noah's example when the language is a propositional language with countably many propositional atoms.

Comment: Ahhhhhh typos.  No idea why I said symmetric difference.  Question is fixed.  But thank you.  Care to make something an answer?

Comment: Asaf, I'm a bit confused about your comment.  It seems to me that every real is a branch through that tree, but of course you can have two reals which differ at only a single coordinate.

Comment: Richard, that depends on her w you represent the reals. If they are actual sets of integers, that's one thing. If they are branches through a tree that's another. Branches in $2^{<\omega}$ are sets of finite functions which have some additional property to them, and you can easily show they form an almost disjoint family. And it's not terribly difficult to code this tree into the integers.

Comment: Fair point, thank you. Care to turn this into an answer, so it can be accepted?

Comment: Which constructions you know of do not result on Borel sets? The standard examples do.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo I presume the construction is the Zorn's Lemma one: first show that there is a maximal almost disjoint family via Zorn, and then show that no countable almost disjoint family is maximal almost disjoint. (And in fact there is no Borel, or even analytic, *maximal* almost disjoint set - this was proved by Mathias in "Happy Families," see the first page of http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/khomskii/papers/Brendle_Khomskii_mad_families_Revised.pdf.)

Comment: @RichardRast. Here is an elaboration of Asaf Karagila's first comment: "tag" each vertex of the binary tree $2^{<\omega}$ by a natural number. Then each branch of the tree gives rise to a unique subset of $\omega$, and any two such subsets are clearly almost disjoint. This family is easily seen to be a Borel uncountable almost disjoint family.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, as commented by Asaf Karagila, it is routine to build a Borel uncountable family of almost disjoint subsets of $\omega$: fix a one-to-one map $f$ from the set $2^{<\omega}$ of finite binary sequences to $\omega$. It is clear that if $B$ and $B'$ are any two distinct branches of $2^{<\omega}$, then $f(B)$ and $f(C)$ are almost disjoint. This makes it evident that the collection of all subsets of $\omega$ of the form $f(B)$, where $B$ is a branch of $2^{<\omega}$, is an uncountable almost disjoint family. I will leave the verification that it is also Borel as an exercise.

> On the other hand, there is no Borel *mad* family, where *mad* stands for *maximal almost disjoint.*  This follows from a theorem of Mathias, who showed that no mad family can even be analytic (analytic = $\Sigma^1_1$ = continuous image of a Borel set).

However, by a joint result of Miller and Kunen, it is consistent with $ZFC$ that there is a co-analytic (i.e., $\Pi^1_1$) mad family, they showed this by building a co-analytic mad family assuming $ZF + V =L$. See [Arnie Miller's wonderful paper](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/infcomb.pdf) for this and other gems exploring definability issues in infinite combinatorics (mad families are treated in sec.8).

Comment: Based on Miller's idea,    Zoltan Vidnyanszky proved a black box theorem  in his paper [Transfinite inductions producing coanalytic sets](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4267). His result   can be used to obtain co-analytic examples in many similar situations.

Answer (score 3):

The answers to this question: [Uncountable family of infinite subsets with pairwise finite intersections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89306/uncountable-family-of-infinite-subsets-with-pairwise-finite-intersections) describe several Borel constructions of uncountable Borel families. (Usually: perfect families)