# Uncountably many subsets of the natural numbers with certain natural density condition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, lo.logic, sequences-and-series

Are there uncountably many $A_\alpha $ of  subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with the following two properties:

1. Each $A_\alpha$ has positive upper natural density
2. $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ is a finite set for $\alpha \neq \beta$

If the answer is no then the next question:

Are there uncountably many $A_\alpha $ of  subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with the following two properties:

1. Each $A_\alpha$ has positive upper natural density
2. $A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ has zero natural density for $\alpha \neq \beta$

**Note:** As indicated [at this MathSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162387/), there are uncountably many infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with pairwise finite intersection. However,
I could not modify the method indicated in the discussion of that post to get an answer to my question.

Comment: See also 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89306/uncountable-family-of-infinite-subsets-with-pairwise-finite-intersections

Comment: Besides @Nik Weaver's answer see Ladislav Mišík and János T. Tóth, [*Large families of almost disjoint large
subsets of* $\mathbb N$](https://www.emis.de/journals/AUSM/) (freely available [.pdf file of the paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/AUSM/C3-1/math31-2.pdf)), **Acta Universitatis Sapientiae. Mathematica** 3 #1 (2011), pp. 26-33 and [this google search of its title](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Large+families+of+almost+disjoint+large+subsets+of%22&filter=0).

Comment: I received the extra 100 points. Really not necessary, but thank you!

Comment: @NikWeaver  You are mostly welcome Nik!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Amazingly, the answer to the main question is yes. For each $n$ let $I_n = [2^{2^n}, 2^{2^{n+1}})$. Then let $\mathcal{C}$ be an uncountable family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ any two of which have finite intersection. For each $B\in \mathcal{C}$ let $B' = \bigcup \{I_n: n \in B\}$. Then $\{B': B \in \mathcal{C}\}$ is the desired family. The point is that if $B$ is any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ then $B'$ has upper density 1.

Edit: or just take $I_n = [n!, (n+1)!)$, so that $\frac{|I_n|}{(n+1)!} = \frac{n}{n+1}$.

Comment: Could you please detail a construction of an uncountable family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ any two of which have finite intersection?

Comment: Sure, an infinite binary tree has countably many vertices. Any two infinite paths down the tree have finite intersection, and there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ of them.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Billion thanks Nik.  I was thinking to this question since 3 or more weeks ago. for the moment I am going out. I will look at it at night.

Comment: You are both welcome. Ali --- it may be a tricky problem because one would think the answer has to be "no". Finding an example wasn't so hard once I realized that's what I was supposed to be doing ...

Comment: Thank you again for your excellent answer

Comment: It was a good question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Your question is answered in the math.SE question that the OP linked to. For each real number $a = 0.a_0a_1a_2a_3\cdots$ between 0 and 1, let $S_a = \{a_0, a_0a_1, a_0a_1a_2, a_0a_1a_2a_3, \ldots\}$.

Comment: @TimothyChow : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @TimothyChow if you think about it, that's practically the same example ...

Comment: @NikWeaver Yes. But this particular phrasing sticks in my mind because right after the [1989 Putnam](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/1989.pdf), a fellow student told me that this is how he had solved Problem B-4, which had stumped me during the exam.

Comment: @TimothyChow  dear Nik and Timothy what about the following stronger version : we require each $A_\alpha$ has positive full density(rather than merely upper density)

Comment: No way. If each $A_\alpha$ has positive density then for some $n$ uncountable many of then have density at least $1/n$. Any $n+1$ of those would would have to have positive density for some $A_\alpha\cap A_\beta$, so the intersection can't be finite.