Is each of the infinite statements of the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis independent?
What I know so far is that:

The Continuum Hypothesis (CH) states $\nexists\mathbb{S}|\beth_0<|S|<\beth_1$

$\beth_0$ being equal to $\aleph_0$, and $\beth_n$ being equal to $2^{\beth_{n-1}}$ for $n \ge 1$


The Generalized Continuum Hypothesis (GCH) states that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \nexists\mathbb{S}|\beth_n<|S|<\beth_{n+1}$

(EDIT: for any ordinal, not just the natural numbers)


Both CH and GCH are independent of ZFC. CH obviously follows GCH, but GCH is independent of ZFC+CH


GCH can be divided into an infinite number of statements, those being:

$\nexists\mathbb{S}|\beth_0<|S|<\beth_1$

This is the Continuum Hypothesis. But I'll be calling it the First Continuum Hypothesis, $1$CH


$\nexists\mathbb{S}|\beth_1<|S|<\beth_2$. The Second Continuum Hypothesis, $2$CH.

$\nexists\mathbb{S}|\beth_2<|S|<\beth_3$ $3$CH.


In general, for all $n$, $n$CH states $\nexists\mathbb{S}|\beth_{n-1}<|S|<\beth_n$
EDIT 2: The part in italics turns out not to be true, as the statement $|\mathbb{A}|<|\mathbb{B}| \implies |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{A})|<|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{B})|$, though intuitive, is actually independent of ZFC.
(EDIT: I thought the below step was valid, but I was assuming that $|\mathbb{A}|<|\mathbb{B}| \implies |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{A})|<|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{B})|$ and although that seems intuitive, I've not been able to prove it)
(I can also show that given a statement $n$CH, $k$CH holds for all $k<n$. This is because if $\exists\mathbb{S}|\beth_{k-1}<|S|<\beth_k$, (not-kCH) then $\beth_{k}<|\mathcal{P}(S)|<\beth_{k+1}$ (not-(k+1)CH), and this would cascade upwards to any $n$.)
--
(My question is, is each $n$CH independent of ZFC+$(n-1)$CH? Or do any of the Continuum Hypotheses imply higher ones?)
(EDIT 2 The original framing of the question made a wrong assumption. The above in italics is the original, the below is the new version. I kept $n$ for a consistent convention even though it represents an ordinal, not necessarily a natural number.)
My question is, is each $n$CH independent of every other under ZFC? Or do some of the Continuum Hypotheses imply some others?

The generalized continuum hypothesis is the even stronger statement that for all ordinals $\alpha$, there is no set $\mathbb S$ where $\beth_\alpha<\vert\mathbb S\vert<\beth_{\alpha+1}$. About the proof that $k$CH implies $k+1$CH, I claim the proof is not correct: why should $\beth_k<\vert\mathcal P(\mathbb S)\vert$ necessarily hold? I also claim that Easton's theorem shows that you can consistently have any desired pattern of $k$CH successes and failures.

As already mentioned, by Easton's theorem the aleph function can do pretty much anything at regular cardinals. There are some restrictions at singular cardinals, for example if GCH holds below a singular $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality, then GCH must also hold at $\kappa$

@C7X oh, yeah I'd missed infinite ordinals.
To clarify, my claim wasn't that $k$CH implies $k+1$CH, it was the converse: that $k+1$CH should imply $k$CH. I got that from assuming not-$k$CH (that is, there does exist such a set), and proving that its power set must have a cardinality that contradicts $k+1$CH.
That said, I did make an assumption listed in an edit that I'm not as sure about as I was.

@SarcasticSully Regarding the principle in your edit, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/6594/1946.

If you are tempted to ask further questions about this topic, I would suggest that math.stackexchange may be a more suitable forum.

In the interest of bringing the question to a conclusion, let me say that it is an immediate consequence of Easton's theorem, as mentioned in the comments, that the various GCH assertions at the $\aleph_n$ or indeed at regular cardinals generally are independent of each other—any GCH pattern whatsoever on regular cardinals can be achieved by forcing.
For example, you can have the GCH hold at $\aleph_n$ exactly when $n$ is prime, or a perfect square, or prime power, or any pattern at all. They are independent.

To clarify, this applies to infinite ordinal $n$ values? Or just natural number $n$ values?

It applies to regular cardinals. This includes all infinite successor cardinals, those of the form $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for any ordinal $\alpha$.
